# Return value along with bool

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to return the value that is queried alone with the bool response but I cant get it right. I'm not getting any errors other than if the search found something or not. The value Subscriberkey is passed into the class from another class. Any changes I make to return that I can think of breaks the code and adding something like

```
if (var == null)
{ 
    return true;
}

return SubscriberQuery.LookupSubProfile(querysubscriber);
```

does not work.

```
public static bool LookupSubProfile (SubscriberProfileQuery subscriber)
{
    try
    {
        var connString = "Server = Server\\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog = Stuff; integrated security = True;";

        var query = "SELECT * FROM Subscriber WHERE SubscriberKey = '@SubscriberKey'";

        query = query.Replace("@SubscriberKey", subscriber.Subscriberkey);

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
        }

        return false; 
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you describe why you are returning a bool at all? Why not either return null on failure, or, even better, throw an exception on failure?

Comment: `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` for a `select` operation?

Comment: I note also that your code is susceptible to injection attacks.

Comment: Also I do not understand why you are executing a query by executing a non-query. Basically none of this makes sense to me; can you explain better what you are trying to do?

Comment: The [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) keyword might be of use to you.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm still very new and this is really my first attempt. I know it has injection issues but this is just an attempt to try and learn web api and im just trying to get some working code so I can learn a few things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's try to fix all the issues present in that code:

1. `ExecuteNonQuery` is not for a `SELECT`, since that's exactly a query.
2. The code is open to SQL Injection, parameters are required.
3. `using` statement already calls `Dispose()` which calls `Close()`, so none of those are required.
4. You don't need to return `bool` when you could just return the value found, `null` if nothing was found or throw the exception if one occurred.

So:

```
public static string LookupSubProfile (SubscriberProfileQuery subscriber)
{
    try
    {
        var connString = "Server = Server\\SQLEXPRESS; initial catalog = Stuff; integrated security = True;";

        var query = "SELECT * FROM Subscriber WHERE SubscriberKey = @SubscriberKey";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                // 2: add parameters
                command.Parameters.Add("SubscriberKey", SqlDataType.VarChar).Value = suscriber.SuscriberKey;

                // 1. use ExecuteScalar/ExecuteReader,
                // you will need to define what exactly you need here
                var result = command.ExecuteScalar();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    // 4. return the result
                    return (string)result;
                }
            }

             // 3. remove unneeded calls
        }

        // 4. return null if nothing was found
        return null; 
    }
    catch
    {
        // 4: throw the error, log if possible
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks @CamiloTerevinto. This answered a lot of my question and I think im on the right path. At least im getting errors I believe I can resolve. you have been a big help. For 2+ point you mind you mind helping me out with one more thing. I subbed out number 2 in favor for what I had before because VS was complaining but im getting  'Must declare the scalar variable "@SubscriberKey".' . I tried converting it to string but I still get that error. if it help in the table its a GUID. Any ideas

Comment: @user3266908, if your parameter value is a GUID, specify `SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier` to match the database column type. Also, note that `ExecuteScalar` returns the value of the first column of the first row returned by the query and discards the rest. It be more appropriate to specify that column name instead of `*` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways,:

1.Using a out parameter and sending it to Method as reference:

```
public static bool LookupSubProfile (SubscriberProfileQuery subscriber,out int someValueToReturn)
{
    ...
    return true;
}
```

the useage would be (an int):

```
int result;
bool value = LookupSubProfile (subscriber,out int result);
```

2.You may return a Tuple:

```
(bool, int) LookupSubProfile() 
{   
    //...        
    return ( true, 3);
}
```

And you could use it like:

```
var (value, result) = LookupSubProfile();
```

Comment: Wouldn't a own class be better practice than a Tuple? Just out of curiousity

Comment: Why `Tuple` and why not create a DTO for the same?

Comment: I am offering possible ways

Comment: Using c# 7 `(value, result)` when the OP clearly does not know the basics is wasting their time trying to understand what that even is. `out` just teaches outdated practices that shouldn't be used unless you have a very good reason to do so.  As @EricLipper said, it'd be much easier to just return `null` in this case. Besides, this doesn't address the multiple problems of the question where this doesn't even matter